# Scrapy: why use pipelines?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, splash-screen

I have a working crawler in Scrapy+Splash. It launchs a spider on many pages. Each page contains a list of links. For each page the spider download the page then, some of the pages linked from that(not recursively).  All the pages are saved on the file system. The system works flawlessy. At the moment I'm refactoring it to add some DB interaction.
**I'm not using items, nor Item Pipelines.
What are the benefits of using them?**

Adding some info:
The purpose of my crawler is to download entire pages (in html, png, or converted to txt using a library). As soon as the spider has the `response` to save, it passes it to a library that encapsulate all the io ops(File system and DB). So in this way, it is simpler than use items(with boilerplate for conversion) and pipelines.
So where is my doubt?
I don't know the way scrapy works internally well enough. The way the crawler is implemented the io ops are executed into the thread of the spider. So each spider takes longer to execute. As opposite if I move the io ops into the pipeline, maybe(?) scrapy can schedule its jobs better, executing them separately from the crawling job. Will there be any real performance difference?

Comment: Check [official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

Comment: I red the offcial documentation yet, and it doesn't answer my question. I know i can use Item Pipelines, their downside is: they require some boilerplate code, their upside is ... what?

Comment: What's wrong if I write on the DB in the spider if there's something?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that but you pollute your spider code with database logic. What if you have two spiders? Do you copy/paste the database logic? That's where pipelines come in - your spiders return dictionary documents and in pipeline you can apply some clean up logic or insert them to database.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, using pipelines is just following the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle. Your spider can do many things, but it's core function is to extract information from web pages. The rest can (and possibly should) be refactored into a pipeline or an extension.

It might not be such an issue if you have one spider for one web site. But imagine you have a Scrapy project with hundreds of spiders for semantically similar web sites and you want to apply the same logic for each item -- take a page snapshot, check for duplicates, store in database etc. And now imagine the maintenance hell if you had all the logic in each of the spiders and had to change that logic.

Comment: well alternatively, one could write an abstract spider class that all your spiders inherit from. And then in that abstract class, you can handle the logic that is the same across all spiders